# Adobe Air badge file not working after Air 3.4 release in nonDebug players

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash

Please read the subject.
All badge installers in the internet are now not working now in non Debug FP(11.3). 
Including mine too.
What does that mean?
Simple example:

> http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/badge_for_air.html

File loads another file from Adobe:

adobe.com../browserapi/air.swf

and checks the AIR version:

```
_air.getStatus(_airVersion)
```

BUT instead of returning a value 'installed' (I have AIR 3.4.0.xxx installed) it returns 'available' and we may see AIR installer dialog instead of the my Application installation.
In last debug player (fp 11.4) after click in the Badger it immediately installs the application without having to install AIR player. Whats wrong?

See my pure example below

> http://smival.com/files/myworks/badge/2/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have it all working fine, I don't suppose you could release the source for this? I am having problems with picking up my application or something; after I click the install button it just sits and does nothing.